# A question on Induction

Tags: inequality, induction

> **Prove that:**  for  any natural number $n\ge10$,  $$2^n\ge n^3.$$
>   How can I prove by induction if $n\ge10$ and I must do that $2^n\ge n^3$?

I stop on this step: $$2^{n+1}\ge n^3+3n^2+3n+1.$$

Here's the question I'm trying to prove. I'm just not certain how I should approach the inductive / constructor step.
I proved  induction wrote $n+1$ instead of $n$.

I think I have everything right until the induction step. But I don’t know what I should do next step, because I had never solve inequality  before I began ask questions on this site.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

The basis for induction is easy (just substitute $n=10$).

For the induction hypothesis, suppose that $n=k$ holds, so $$2^k\ge k^3$$ for some $k\ge 10$.

Consider $n=k+1$:

$$2^{k+1}=2\cdot2^k\ge2k^3$$ and all you have to do now is show that $$2k^3\ge(k+1)^3$$ for $k\ge10$.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't understand why I should show that 2k3≥(k+1)3. You wrote above 2k+1=2⋅2k≥2k3. There I should prove that

Comment: 2k3<=2k+1=2⋅2k.

Comment: No, you already know that $2^{k+1}=2\cdot2^k\ge2k^3$ *from the induction hypothesis*! So to show that $$2^{k+1}\ge(k+1)^3$$ you just have to prove the final polynomial inequality.

Comment: And how have I prove  the final polynomial inequality?

Comment: Show some attempt first then I'll provide a further hint should you require one.

Comment: But I don't know how I should do first step.

Comment: Well do you know of the Binomial Theorem?

Comment: No, I don't know.

Comment: OK, then expand $(k+1)^3=(k+1)(k+1)(k+1)$. Can you do that?

Comment: Yes, I can do that . Thank you very much! I must to go.

Answer (score 0):

$2^(n+1) = 2^n*2 >= 2n^3$

Compare $2n^3$ to $n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1$

$n^3 vs. 3n^2 + 3n + 1$

We can start to see that the left hand side is greater than the right hand side for n>=10. It is true at n=10.

Consider each side as two functions. Then taking derivatives we have $3n^2$ and $6n + 3$

The left function is increasing faster than the right function for n > 10.